# Laravel 4 Query with 30 Days Ago Condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I dont understand where goes wrong. When I add this

> where('units.solddate','>=','DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)')

where clause and my result is empty. I tried in phpMyadmin and it does return results.

```
$query= (tables)
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(units.price) as price, DATE(units.solddate) as date, DAY(units.solddate) as day'))
        ->where('units.solddate','>=','DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)')
        ->where('units.solddate','<=','NOW()')
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->get();
```

Please advice.

Comment: If `solddate` is a datetime then use `now()` instead of `CURDATE()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the constraints don't work is that Eloquent takes the value you compare with literally, escapes it when needed and then uses in a query. So if you do

```
->where('units.solddate','<=','NOW()')
```

you're in fact comparing **units.solddate** with a strin **NOW()**, like in:

```
... WHERE units.solddate <= 'NOW()'
```

If you want to use MySQL functions in your query you have to explicitely tell Eloquent/QueryBuilder that you mean the raw value that you provided by using **DB::raw()** to wrap the value.

The following should work for you:

```
->where('units.solddate','>=',DB::raw('DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)'))
->where('units.solddate','<=',DB::raw('NOW()'))
```

Comment: woww thanks! didnt know would treat NOW() as string. Thank you :D